# How to calculate voltage drop across a coaxial transmission line?

Tags: transmission-line, coaxial

I am an engineering student and I want to ask a question for my assignment.

How can I calculate voltage amplitude drop across a coaxial transmission line without input function? (How many percent of amplitude is dropped across certain distance?)

In my understanding, the voltage at certain point can be predicted as:

[image]

To predict amplitude drop across distance, we just need to calculate this term:

[image]

This term is the percentage of amplitude at certain point.

But isn't k and gamma calculated from input function?

Comment: There's a lot more to it than that.  Cables have impedance and DC ohms and require impedance matching for MPT and low return loss. Pls link where you found this.

Comment: https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/transmission-line-loss

Comment: Usually you would know the dB loss per meter and then just multiply that by the number of meters